# XSLT: Match first descendant element

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to match the first `bar` element that occurs as a descendant of a `foo` element in an xsl match pattern and struggling. Initial attempt:

```
<xsl:template match="//foo//bar[1]">
...
</xsl:template>
```

fails because there are several `bar` elements that match. So:

```
<xsl:template match="(//foo//bar)[1]">
...
</xsl:template>
```

but that fails to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Tricky.  I don't know how efficient or otherwise this would be, but you could turn the pattern on its head and move the logic into a predicate (which *is* allowed to use axes other than child, attribute and `//`):

```
<xsl:template match="foo//bar[not(preceding::bar/ancestor::foo)]">
```

(any `bar` inside a `foo` provided there isn't another bar-inside-a-foo before it).  Alternatively you could try a key trick similar to the way Muenchian grouping works, which may be more efficient

```
<!-- trick key - all matching nodes will end up with the same key value - all
     we care about is finding whether a particular node is the first such node
     in the document or not. -->
<xsl:key name="fooBar" match="foo//bar" use="1" />

<xsl:template match="foo//bar[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fooBar', 1)[1])]">
```

Comment: I think that would match the first `<bar>` in the file only, not the first `<bar>` per `<foo>`.

Comment: @Tomalak that's what I took "the first bar element that occurs as a descendant of a foo" to mean - the single node that would be selected by the XPath `(//foo//bar)[1]`.

Comment: ... as opposed to "the first bar element that occurs as a descendant of _each_ foo".  We'll have to wait for the OP to confirm which interpretation is correct.

Comment: I was extrapolating from the fact that the OP is trying to write a template, something that would not strictly be necessary if one expects a single execution. But you're right, it is ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, there happens to be a single foo in the document - does that clarify?

Comment: @BobbyJack then either mine or Tomalak's solutions should work equally well.

Comment: @BobbyJack If there's only ever a single foo in the entire document, why go through all the trouble?

Comment: @Ian: Thanks. I can confirm that Tomalak's does. However, I prefer the look of your first example, so I might give that a go.

Comment: @Tomalak: That sounds like it deserves a very good answer, which I can't give, I'm afraid. The short and unsatisfactory answer is that I'm converting from a bunch of XPATH expressions that were doing an equivalent of XSLT via DOM queries and manipulations. I'm a straight conversion is probably not the most sensible and/or efficient method, granted.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You cannot do this with match expressions.</strike> In fact, you *can* do this with match expressions, just not in every XSLT processor, as it seems. See comments.

I'd use an `<xsl:if>`.

```
<xsl:template match="foo//bar">
  <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(ancestor::foo[1]//bar)">
    <!-- ... -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This ensures that only *the first descendant `<bar>` per `<foo>`* (!) is processed any further.

NB: When given a node-set, `generate-id()` returns the ID of the first node in the set.

Comment: In fact that _could_ be moved into the match expression, as `match="foo//bar[generate-id() = generate-id(ancestor::foo[1]//bar)]"`, since you don't have the restriction on which axes you can use once you're inside a predicate.

Comment: @IanRoberts I thought that as well, but it did not work in my test. Would you try it and confirm?

Comment: Works for me using xsltproc (XSLT 1.0), fails with a type error on Saxon 9 HE (XSLT 2.0) because `generate-id` expects a single node rather than a sequence.

Comment: Saxon is happy if I change the expression to ensure a single node (`generate-id(ancestor::foo[1]/descendant::bar[1])`)

Comment: Okay, the XSLT 2.0 error could be countered with `generate-id((ancestor::foo[1]//bar)[1])` (your `generate-id(ancestor::foo[1]/descendant::bar[1])` is not the same thing, it selects *all* descendant `<bar>` that are first in their respective parent).

Comment: No, that's what `...//bar[1]` would select (which is equivalent to `.../descendant-or-self::node()/child::bar[1]`), this is different from `.../descendant::bar[1]`

Comment: @Ian You are right again (I even believe we discussed that already). BTW, both `msxsl.exe` (i.e. MSXML2) and xmlplayground.com (PHP/libxslt) match *all* nodes when the predicate is moved from the `<xsl:if>` to the match expression. Curious, I'd be very interested to know if that's correct behavior or not in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is based on the "rule of thumb" use advanced XPATH with "select" not when you "match".  Match XML with templates simply by name like foo, not even //foo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
<bar>bar1<bar>bar2</bar></bar>
<bar>bar3</bar>
</foo>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="foo">
<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::bar[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
<!--only the first bar was selected --><xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's fine if you _only_ want to process the first one, but the usual point of matching templates is that you want to process all nodes in document order but handle the first bar-in-a-foo differently from the subsequent ones.

Comment: And `//foo//bar[1]` _is_ allowed in a match expression, the point of the question is that it matches too many nodes (any bar inside a foo  where that bar is the first bar inside its direct parent, not just the first bar descendant of a foo).

Comment: I totally agree with you,but my solution is often all we need.

Comment: Not all XPATH expressions are allowed with XPATH,  descendant::bar[1] can not be used with match.

Comment: Precisely.  Axes like `descendant::` are not allowed but `//` _is_.